# babel-jest can't find https

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am using jest/babel-jest to write a node application, am using `https` module.

```
babel.config.js

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Test file:

```
import { https } from 'https';

// do some stuff

https.request(...);
```

But when I run jest I get this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
```

Why won't jest let me make an http request?

I know I'm doing something stupid, I just don't know what :P

Comment: do you have `babel-jest` installed? if no, babel transform is not applied.

Comment: may it be `https` is default import not named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import https from 'https';
```